# Neo4J Docker-compose Loading CSV data at startup

Tags: docker, csv, import, neo4j, docker-compose

I am trying to write a small python web service that calls a Neo4J database. This is purely in a development environment. I would like to load some CSV data when the Neo4J container starts.

I have tried using the `EXTENSION_SCRIPT` environment setting to load data with a script like

```
#!/bin/bash

load()
{
    echo "Loading data"
    neo4j-admin import --nodes=/var/lib/neo4j/import/test.csv
}

load
```

I keep getting errors of the following form `WARNING Import failed. The store files in /data/databases/neo4j are left as they are, although they are likely in an unusable state`

I am assuming that the load needs to happen before `neo4j` is started as there is some lock on the db files. Has anyone solved this problem ?

My Docker-compose is as follows:

```
neo4j:
    build: ./graph
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: 
      - 7474:7474
      - 7687:7687
    volumes:
      - ./conf:/conf
      - ./data:/data
      - ./import:/import
      - ./logs:/logs
      - ./plugins:/plugins
    environment: 
      # Raise memory limits
      - NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=1G
      - NEO4J_dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=1G
      - NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_max__size=1G
```

And my Dockerfile :

```
FROM neo4j:latest

WORKDIR /

COPY load.sh /load.sh
RUN chmod +x /load.sh

ENV EXTENSION_SCRIPT=load.sh

COPY test.csv /var/lib/neo4j/import/test.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

neo4j-admin import can only be used to load data into a previously unused database.
you should run the load.sh as part of the dockerfile after the COPY.

```
RUN /load.sh
```

Comment: Is there anyway to load data into an existing DB, or do I need to use Cypher for that ?

Comment: there is also kettle. but I think for one time job as part of the image its better to write Cypher . see https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/

Comment: Yeah, I saw that for whatever reason , I have not managed to get this to work at container start, I think timing issues. Eventually I used `load` from within an application.